# IIS SMTP Server

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis, smtp

I am trying to set up an SMTP server on a virtual private server. I have typically hosted applications with hosting companies in the past.

I am using SMPT on a website to send mail but need to configure IIS's SMTP Server to allow me to send the mail. I have a couple of questions around this:

1.What settings do I need to set to enable me to hit mail.myDomain.com and provide a user name and password for the mail to send?
2.What security issues do I need to be aware of and how do I lock down the SMTP server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an externally acessible SMTP server avalaible, just target it directly from your .NET code?

The `<system.net>` section in your config has some mail server settings you can use.